# How to add multiple parameters of DIFFERENT DATA TYPES in retrofit

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I have problems adding multiple params in retrofit. The main problem is, I dont want to use **@Query** annotation for many params, it's tiresome and not efficient. On the other hand, using **@FieldMap**  only allows for `Map<String, String>` meaning all params have to be strings and this is not realistic. Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up populating the parameters in a `JSONObject` then passed it's **json string** as one String param with `@Query` annotation then I parse the **json string** on the server side.